# IP Tables, is it possible to limit requests per minute and timeout IP?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup a firewall that limits to 3 connections per IP and also ban the IP for an hour if > 30 connection attempts in one minute.  This is for port 80 only. Is this all possible with iptables?  I also use fail2ban.

So far I have only limited the connections per IP using the following

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Any ideas what I module I would need to do this?

Here are my current rules

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 --connlimit-mask 32 --connlimit-saddr -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPtables itself works great to manage INPUT, OUTPUT, MASQ, Etc, however it's limited to manager services, protocols and sources for timeout.

You must install Fail2ban and create Chains for different kinds of services that you want to manage.

Check this link and get it done.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score -2):

Check iptables **recent** module,

Here is some good example - http://thiemonagel.de/2006/02/preventing-brute-force-attacks-using-iptables-recent-matching/

Comment: It is preferred that you give content *here* and link elsewhere for more detail if necessary.